# Pytorch Dataloader for multiple data to feed CNN and encoder

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, dataloader

I am trying to run a CNN & encoder model to finish Classification Task, they are fed with different inputs and I don't know how to make different scale data into one dataloader. CNN : encoder = 1:10

one step, CNN receive 1 piece of data and encoder receive 10 pieces, then the model gets a 10 pieces of output.
do i have to repeat 10 times CNN data to keep same scale?  because one cnn input are same for 10 output per step.

My current dataset code:

```py
def dataset(x_train ,y_train, x_eval, y_eval, x_image_train, x_image_eval):
    print("TensorDataset")
    # encoder input and model labels
    x_train  = torch.from_numpy(x_train.astype(np.float32))
    y_train = torch.from_numpy(y_train.astype(np.float32))
    x_eval  = torch.from_numpy(x_eval.astype(np.float32))
    y_eval = torch.from_numpy(y_eval.astype(np.float32))

    # CNN input
    x_image_train = torch.from_numpy(x_image_train.astype(np.float32))
    x_image_eval = torch.from_numpy(x_image_eval.astype(np.float32))
   
    
    train_data = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(x_train, x_image_train, y_train)
    eval_data = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(x_eval,x_image_eval, y_eval)
    
    return train_data, eval_data
```

dataloader code

```py
train_sampler = torch.utils.data.distributed.DistributedSampler(train_data)
train_batch_sampler = torch.utils.data.BatchSampler(train_sampler, batch_size, drop_last=True)
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_data,
                                            batch_sampler=train_batch_sampler,
                                             pin_memory=True,
                                             num_workers=nw)
```

`

Maybe I could get 2 dataloaders for the model, but how can I ensure they are fed in order?

Comment: From what I understand, you are looking to combine two dataloaders, one is supposed to output single elements, while the other one outputs 10?

Comment: exactly, the cnn dataloader is supposed to output single elements, and for every 10 outputs of encoder, the output of cnn is the same. In order to save storage space, I don't want to copy 10  of cnn data, is there any better way? @Ivan

Comment: Could you try to explain your use case again?

Comment: Sure. The model consists two: encoder and CNN. Each step, CNN and encoder will be fed with different data, both one element, then model concats the output of the two in the FC.  My problem is, for each 10 step, CNN input corresponding to encoder is the same while encoder is different . To save storage, for every 10 step, I only save one CNN element and need to feed 10 times. eg. CNN input shape(410,3,32) while encoder (4100, 3,10). I know I can expand CNN input into (4100,3,32) at the expense of space, but my data is large, how can I do better? I don't know if I explained clearly sryTT @Ivan